# Console.log data from HTML form input

Tags: javascript, forms, console.log

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NYaeXV

I am trying to log the value of a HTML form input. I put multiple options inside the CodePen. Here is my initial thought process.

```
<form action="">
<input type="text" name="data" id="data">
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

function sConsole() {
  var data = document.getElementById("data");
  console.log(data.value());
}
sConsole();
```

Comment: value is NOT a method, it is an attribute. Drop the `()`. Also your code is going to run on page load, so there will be no value in the input unless you set the default. So you probably are looking to bind it onchange of the input, or onsubmit of the form.

Comment: Sorry, but it would be **easier** and **faster** for you just to read the documentation instead of asking this question.

Comment: @epascarello thank you! This definitely pointed me in the right direction.  Once I had taken out the `()` from .value it started to show it's initial value `""`  on page load like you said. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Since your meaning is clear for me, even the syntax is not! I found your question useful and vote it up!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `value` instead of `value()` since `value` is not a function , also consider using `e.preventDefault()` to avoid the page reload one more thing , by adding `sConsole()` into your js file you're asking the function to be executed when the page load, you need to move your function to the submit event instead.

Here is a working example and Happy coding :)

```js
function sConsole(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var data = document.getElementById("data");
  console.log(data.value);
  
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
  <h4>Input your console data below : </h4>
  <form action="" id="form" onsubmit="sConsole(event)">
    <input type="text" name="data" id="data">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes! The onsubmit! That was the big thing I was forgetting! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You missed `onclick` or `onSubmit` , you should also use `.value`

```js
function sConsole() {
  var data = document.getElementById("data");
  console.log(data.value);
  //!!Option 1a
  //console.log(data.submit());
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
  <h4>Input your console data below : </h4>
  <form action="">
    <input type="text" name="data" id="data">
    <button type="submit" onClick="sConsole()">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close, just a few things to consider.

### Getting the value of an input field

The value attribute of an input element stores the text in the textbox. To retrieve, this in javascript, use `ExampleElement.value`, for example:

```
var dataValue = document.getElementById("data").value;
```

or

```
var data = document.getElementById("data");
var dataValue = data.value;
```

You can also specify the value attribute in the input tag with `value=""`. This is useful if you want to prefill the input text box, for instance, if you send the user input to a php script for action and wanted to return the textbox with information already included.

### Calling a Javascript Function

There are multiple ways to call a javascript function, including doing so when certain events occur. In your situation, you probably want the input value logged every time the user clicks submit. You could add an event listener, but for simplicity sake of understanding, let's just use inline code. Every time they submit, let's log it, so `onsubmit="sConsole();"`. Now the submit action will run your logging function.

If you wanted to log every change while the user was typing, you would use an event listener with more complex evaluation of the input value.

### Prevent Default

It's likely that you don't want the form to actually be submitted to the server and page reloaded every time the user clicks submit. By using `event.preventDefault();`, javascript prevents the usual action of submitting the form to the server and instead leaves the user input and the page as is.

If you want the textbox to be "erases" after each submit, it's probably best to reset the value in your function rather than submitting the form. To reset the value, you would simply do `data.value = ""`.

### Code Example

Putting it all together, here's an example code segment with comments about your original sample.

```
<form action="" onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); sConsole();"> <!-- use inline JS to print input to console on submit -->
<input type="text" name="data" id="data">
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
function sConsole() {
  var data = document.getElementById("data");
  console.log(data.value); // data is the element, and we want its value
}
//sConsole(); This would call it only on script load, which isn't what you want
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the detail! Definitely a lot to remember

Answer (score 0):

```js
function sConsole(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var data = document.getElementById("data");
  console.log(data.value);
  
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
  <h4>Input your console data below : </h4>
  <form action="" id="form" onsubmit="sConsole(event)">
    <input type="text" name="data" id="data">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```